# Command line export of ERD diagram to PDF or HTML in oracle data modeler (sql-developer)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, erd, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I use now data modeler for quite a while and export for documentation purposes the ERD diagram to PDF and HTML.

Is there a command line utility to update the model (synchronize model with data dictionary) and then export the PDF / HTML.

Reason is that we want to include this documentation step in our build pipeline ...

If not ... are there any other tools out there you know ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We're building CLI support for the modeler... You'll see model commands in SQLcl later this year to do things like you're describing.

If you use the reporting repository in the modeler, you can [query the data dictionary](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/06/querying-your-oracle-sql-developer-data-modeler-designs/) and the diagrams (as blobs) today...